# Is analysis of variance here a correct test?

Tags: anova, independence

Suppose I have measurements:

- $f(x_i, y_i)$
- $f(v_i, w_i)$
- $f(x_i, v_i)$
- $f(y_i, w_i)$

If I put these into groups $(xy), (vw)$ and $(xv, yw)$ and do a single-factor ANOVA with the previous three groups, is it still valid? So $(xy)$ and $(vw)$ are independent of each other. The samples in the last group $(xv, yw)$ are independent within the group but not between groups. If other assumptions of ANOVA (normal distributions, equal variances) are OK, how bad is this violation?